# MongoDB No converter found capable of converting from type org.bson.types.ObjectId to type java.lang.Long

Tags: spring, mongodb

I have the following Model for a Customer that is used by Postgres and MongoDB. It works fine with Postgres but I get this error when I want to list all Customers from MongoDB:

> org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from type
>   org.bson.types.ObjectId to type java.lang.Long

Here is my model class:

```
package com.example.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder;

@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "customer")
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(String fn, String ln) {
        this.firstName = fn;
        this.lastName = ln;
    }

    public Customer(Long id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id", required = false)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name = "first-name", required = false)
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }


    @XmlAttribute(name = "last-name", required = false)
    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
    }
}
```

Here is my CustomerService to retrieve all Customers:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.model.Customer;
import com.example.service.CustomerService;

@Service
@Import({ MongoConfiguration.class })
public class MongoCustomerService implements CustomerService{   

    @Inject MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    Class<Customer> entityClass = Customer.class;

    @Override
    public Collection<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
        try {
             List<Customer> allCustomers = mongoTemplate.findAll(entityClass);
             return allCustomers;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

My pom.xml:

```
          </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either your `id` field needs to be called `_id`, or you need to annotate it with @Id.  See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.4.0.M1/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html#d0e5192).

Comment: In my case I have and _id which is autogenerated and id then one I created and I got the same error. Do you have a suggestion?

Answer (score 16):

I changed the id from Long to BigInteger and it worked as per the documentation.

Comment: @Trisha's answer was not enough for me. I had to also apply this to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Make field _id and annotate with @Id . Make type as Big Integer

Comment: Please update to include a small explanation of why this works.

Answer (score 1):

## Following are the three steps that I did to get mongo running on Grails(2.3.4):

I have mongo db instance with persons collection.

### 1. DataSource.groovy

```
grails {
    mongo {
        host = "localhost"
        port = 27017
        databaseName = "<db Name>"
    }
}
```

### 2. BuildConfig.groovy

```
plugins {

        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.47"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.0.1"
        compile ':cache:1.1.1'
        **compile ":mongodb:1.3.1"**

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.6" // or ":hibernate4:4.1.11.6"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"
        runtime ":jquery:1.10.2.2"
        runtime ":resources:1.2.1"
     }
```

### 3. Domain definition:

```
package mongo
class Person{
String id
Sting name

static mapWith="mongo"

static mapping={
 collection "persons"
 database "<dbName>"

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an error when in my table was presented ids with different types. After deleting all wrong ids my app worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
```

then
use ObjectId _id instead of Long id;

```
@Id
private ObjectId _id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

```js
# insert data in MongoDB
db.createCollection('order')
db.order.insert([
    {
        "order_number": 1,
        "order_name" : "order1"
    }
])
```

```java
@Document("order")
@Setter
@Getter
public class  Order{

    @Id
    private Integer orderNumber;

    private String orderName;
}
```

then I changed the issue to go away

```js
# insert data in MongoDB
db.order.insert([
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "order_name" : "order1"
    }
])
```

More information [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.id-handling)